# Evaluating a symbolic sum

Tags: symbolic, summation

I have read how *Mathematica* does not have an easy time with symbolic sums, but nevertheless would like to know if anyone can suggest an approach to help *Mathematica* along.

For:

```
Sum[(1 - j + m)^(-1 + n) , {j, 1, m - 1}]
```

I get:

```
-0^(-1 + n) + (-1)^(1 + n) HurwitzZeta[1 - n, -m]
```

however with an extra factor of `j`:

```
Sum[(1 - j + m)^(-1 + n) j, {j, 1, m - 1}]
```

it returns unevaluated.

Are there add-on packages which are more successful? Is anyone aware of *different* software that might do the trick?

Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but setting `n` to a positive integer (and not setting a value for `m`) does result in a symbolic result.

Comment: @JimB, yes, thank you, I did notice that. And also, that the opposite is not true (i.e., setting only `m` to a positive integer).

Comment: Redenoting `1-j+m` by `k` gives `Sum[(m - k + 1) k^(n - 1), {k, 2, m}]` which evaluates to `-m + (1 + m) HarmonicNumber[m, 1 - n] - HarmonicNumber[m, -n]`

Comment: მამუკა ჯიბლაძე -- thank you for this tip.

Answer (score 15):

Consider:

```
sum = Inactive[Sum][(1 - a j + m)^n, {j, 1, m - 1}];
```

and differentiate with respect to `a`:

```
D[sum, a]
```

> Inactive[Sum][-j (1 - a j + m)^(-1 + n) n, {j, 1, -1 + m}]

Up to a factor of `-n` (and the presence of the parameter `a`), this is the sum you're trying to evaluate. So, you're desired result is:

```
r[m_, n_] = -D[Activate @ sum, a]/n /. a->1
```

> (1/n)((-1)^(
>      1 + n) (-(1 + m) n HurwitzZeta[1 - n, -1] + (1 + m) n HurwitzZeta[
>          1 - n, -m]) + (-1)^(-1 + n)
>       n (-HurwitzZeta[-n, -1] + HurwitzZeta[-n, -m]))

Let's check with some examples. Here's the definition of your sum:

```
s[m_, n_] := Sum[(1 - j + m)^(n-1) j, {j, 1, m-1}]
```

And, here's a table of the difference between the result above and your sum for values of `m` and `n` running from 1 to 10:

```
Table[s[m, n] - r[m, n], {m, 10}, {n, 10}] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Carl Woll -- great technique! Thank you so much! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple algebraic solution.

The trick is to consider a factor `(1-j+m)` instead of just a factor `j`, and then subtract the access part `(1+m)`.

Here we go

The sum being immediately evaluated is

```
s0[n_, m_] := Sum[(1 - j + m)^(n - 1), {j, 1, m - 1}]

s0[n, m]

(* Out[6]= -0^(-1 + n) + (-1)^(1 + n) HurwitzZeta[1 - n, -m] *)
```

The problem of the OP is the observation that the sum with the factor `j`

```
sjU[n_, m_] := Sum[(j) (1 - j + m)^(n - 1), {j, 1, m - 1}]
```

is returned unevaluated.

Now consider that the sum `s0[n+1]` which has an additional factor `(1 - j + m)`

```
s0[n + 1, m] == Sum[(1 - j + m) (1 - j + m)^(n - 1), {j, 1, m - 1}]

(* Out[8]= True *)
```

is evaluated.

Noticing that

```
(1 - j + m) == -j + (1 + m)
```

the value `sjV` of our unevaluated sum `sjU` can be written as a difference

```
sjV[n_, m_] := -s0[n + 1, m] + (1 + m) s0[n, m]
```

Comparison between `sjU` and `sjV`

```
And @@ Table[sjU[n, m] == sjV[n, m] // FullSimplify, {n, 1, 10}]

(* Out[10]= True *)
```

shows agrrement.

**Discussion**

It is interesting that the sum with the upper summation index extended from `m-1` to `m`

```
s1[n_, m_] := Sum[(1 - j + m)^(n - 1), {j, 1, m }]
```

$\text{Out:  }\sum _{j=1}^m (-j+m+1)^{n-1}$

is returned unevaluated (Version 10.1.0).

While shifting the upper index further, to `m+1`, works

```
Sum[(1 + m - j)^(n - 1), {j, 1, m + 1}]

(* Out[25]= (-1)^(1 + n) (HurwitzZeta[1 - n, -m] - Zeta[1 - n]) *)
```

Hence only the sum ending in the seemingly harmelss term `1^(n-1)` is not evaluated.

Comment: Thank you very much for that insightful and helpful trick. Regarding your final comment in the Discussion, it is frustrating to me that, as you showed, the chance of getting a result seems to be highly unpredictable. This is especially true, since from my reading and understanding, the method of the symbolic summation is to first look at the summand only, and if it can be solved, then to plug in the limits of the summation.